# Is it possible to call a jQuery function on the all nodes from Datatable at once?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is it possible to call `removeClass` on all `nodes`from `DataTable`without using a loop?

```
var selectedNodes = dataTable.rows('.' + rowSelectedClass).nodes();
selectedNodes.each(function (value, index) { // works, but have to use each
    $(value).removeClass(rowSelectedClass);
});

// selectedNodes.removeClass(rowSelectedClass); // selectedNodes.removeClass is not a function
// selectedNodes.items().removeClass(rowSelectedClass); // Is something like this possible?
```

**Solution** *Credit @annoyingmouse*

```
dataTable.rows('.' + rowSelectedClass).nodes().to$().removeClass('rowSelectedClass');
```

Comment: I know selectedNodes aren't a jQuery object, but is there some kind of "ConvertNodesTojQuery()"?

Comment: I was looking into this yesterday and came across this: to$() https://datatables.net/reference/api/to$()

Comment: @annoyingmouse Perfect, it's excatly what I was looking for, please make it to an answer to I can honor you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time looking into this myself I discovered the really rather marvelous [to$()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/to$()) api method, basically it creates:

> a jQuery object from the contents of the API instance's result set.

I trust that does what you require?